# Tracing recursive function using XCode debugger

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, recursion

How do I trace recursive functions like these that calls itself recursively two times? I wanted to create a tree of the calls. When I stumbled into this, how do I know which of the methods that currently are being executed? `CountWays(numStairs-1)` or `CountWays(numStairs-2)`

[image]

Comment: The "tree of the calls" you're looking for is called a stack trace or back trace. I don't use xcode, but I assume there's a window or toolbar to display it.

Comment: `When I stumbled into this, how do I know wich of the methods that currently are being executed?` Why do you want to do that at all? Are you trying to understand how it works? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GDB answer?**
If you see near the bottom-right of your screenshot there are 3 buttons in a group and the left-most button has been selected. Press either the center or the far-right button to open the debug console.  In there you may type 'bt' and it will print your back-trace.

**GUI answer?** 
You need to trigger a backtrace upon your breakpoint (or exception breakpoint), instructions for this can be found here:
http://www.oramind.com/index.php/articles/182-ios-5-xcode-backtrace

Comment: the link is broken